# Unable to parse div tag using beautiful soup in python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning to use beautiful soup to parse div containers from html. But for some reason, when i pass the class name of the div containers to my beautiful soup, nothing happens. I am getting no element when i try to parse the div. What could i be doing wrong. here is my html and the parse

```
                                  <div class="upcoming-date ng-hide no-league" ng-show="nav.upcoming" ng-class="{'no-league': !search.checkShowTitle(nav.sport,nav.todayHighlights,nav.upcoming,nav.orderBy,&quot;FOOTBALL - HIGHLIGHTS&quot;)}">
                        <span class="weekday">Monday</span>
                        <timecomponent datetime="'2018-07-09T20:00:00+03:00'" show-date="true" show-time="false" class="date ng-isolate-scope"><span class="ng-binding">09/07/18</span></timecomponent>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>





            <div id="g1390856" class="match football FOOTBALL - HIGHLIGHTS" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/SportsEvent">
    <div class="leaguename ng-hide" ng-show="search.checkShowTitle(nav.sport,nav.todayHighlights,nav.upcoming,nav.orderBy,&quot;FOOTBALL - HIGHLIGHTS&quot;) &amp;&amp; (1 || (nav.upcoming &amp;&amp; 0))">
      <span class="name">
        <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-swe"></span>
          Sweden - Allsvenskan
      </span>
    </div>

    <ul class="meta">
        <li class="date">
            <timecomponent datetime="'2018-07-09T20:00:00+03:00'" show-date="true" show-time="false" class="ng-isolate-scope"><span class="ng-binding">09/07/18</span></timecomponent>
        </li>
        <li class="time">
            <timecomponent datetime="'2018-07-09T20:00:00+03:00'" show-date="false" show-time="true" class="ng-isolate-scope"><span class="ng-binding">20:00</span></timecomponent>
        </li>
        <li class="game-id"><span class="gameid">GameID:</span> 2087</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="teams">
    <li>Hammarby</li>
    <li>Ostersunds</li>
</ul>
    <ul class="bet-selector">
        <li class="pick01" id="b499795664">
    <a data-id="499795664" ng-click="bets.pick($event, 499795664, 2087, 2.10)" class="betting-button pick-button " title="Hammarby">

                                        <span class="team">Hammarby</span>
                <span class="odd">2.10</span>
    </a>
</li>                    <li class="pick0X" id="b499795666">
    <a data-id="499795666" ng-click="bets.pick($event, 499795666, 2087, 3.56)" class="betting-button pick-button " title="Draw">
                                                <span class="team">Draw</span>
                <span class="odd">3.56</span>
    </a>
</li>                <li class="pick02" id="b499795668">
    <a data-id="499795668" ng-click="bets.pick($event, 499795668, 2087, 3.40)" class="betting-button pick-button " title="Ostersunds">

                                        <span class="team">Ostersunds</span>
                <span class="odd">3.40</span>
    </a>
</li>    </ul>
            <ul class="extra-picks">
                        <li>
                <a class="betting-button " href="/games/1390856/markets?league=0&amp;top=0&amp;sid=2087&amp;sportId=1">
                    <span class="short-desc">+13</span>
                    <span class="long-desc">View 13 more markets</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="game-stats">
                <a href="https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sportpesa/en/match/13414729" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=1024, height=800, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes'); return false;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/img/chart-icon.png?v2.2.25.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

.............................................................

```
parser.py

import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
udata = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/?sportId=1')
htmlsource = udata.read()
ssoup = soup(htmlsource,'html.parser')
page_div = ssoup.findAll("div",{"class":"match football FOOTBALL - HIGHLIGHTS"})

print page_div
```

Answer (score 1):

"match football FOOTBALL - HIGHLIGHTS" is a dynamic class so you are just getting a blank list....
Here is my code in python3

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
request = requests.get('https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/?sportId=1')
soup = bs4(request.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

After printing soup you will find that this class is not present in your source code... I hope that it will help you

Comment: :- Thank you. I just looked and found out that the classes are generated dynamically, So, is it still possible to scrape websites like this? I looked at the html code that i got after parsing using beautifulsoup and its completely different than the html that i see in my browser

Comment: It's not possible with Beautiful soup... but if you want to scrape dynamic data then you can use selenium.

Comment: Most ofter you can fetch the data from the same apis that javascript use to populate the page. Use Chrome Dev Tools and check out wha's going on in the networks tab when you load the page. Usually there'll be good stuff up for grabs under XHR...

Answer (score 0):

So - as suggested in the comment - the best (fastest) way to get data from this site is to make use of the same endpoint, that the javascript uses.

If you use Chrome, pop up the Inspector Tool, open the networks tab and load the page. You'll see, that se site gets the data from a url, that looks very similar to the one actually displayed in the url, namely

> https://sportpesa.co.ke/sportgames?sportId=1

This endpoint gives you the data you need. To grab it using requests and getting the divs, you want, would be done like below:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://sportpesa.co.ke/sportgames?sportId=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser") 
page_divs = soup.select('div.match.football.FOOTBALL.-.HIGHLIGHTS')
print(len(page_divs))
```

That prints 30 - which is the number of divs. Btw I'm using the bs4-method select here, which is the bs4-recommended way of doing things, when you - as you do here - have not just one but multiple classes ('match', 'football', 'FOOTBALL', '-' and 'HIGHLIGHTS').